# How to find the L1-Norm/Manhattan distance between two vectors in Python without libraries

Tags: python-3.x, function, vector, linear-algebra, algebra

I have two vectors with equal dimensions and need to find the distance between them

I have tried various approaches:

```
sum([a-b for a, b in zip(u, v)])
```

```
c= sum([a-b for a, b in zip(u, v)]
#If x is negative, multiply by negative one to convert x to a positive
if c<=0:
    return c*-1
#No changes are made to x if it is positive
else:
    return c
```

I am yet to have success!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `abs()` function, which is available in standard python.

So if you have

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,.4]
b = [4,3,4,5,-2,.8]
```

Than you can get the distance with

```
sum([abs(i-j) for i,j in zip(a,b)])
```

We can use the `sklearn` implementation to check indeed this is the correct answer.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import manhattan_distances
manhattan_distances([a], [b])
```